# How can I slow down the framerate of a Flash game?

Tags: windows-7, speed, adobe-flash

I am trying to play an Adobe Flash game in my browser. The only problem is that it is too fast for me. I know it would be "cheating", but I would enjoy the game more if I could play it at a slower pace.

I've tried throttling the CPU, but I don't think this approach is reliable.

How can I have my browser or the Flash plugin play the game at a slower framerate?

Comment: Does it have to affect only that process? Because temporarily underclocking the CPU is easy.

Comment: If only they hadn't gotten rid of the 'Turbo' button...

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question. That question is about how to limit the CPU usage. This question is about how to *slow down the clock* of a program, so that the game's UI runs more slowly.

Comment: @wizlog: Limiting CPU usage will just make the game stutter (if it's CPU-bound) or nothing otherwise. What you want is to slow down the clock to a playable speed.

Comment: @wizlog I know of a Windows solution for Flash games specifically. If you reword your question to be about Adobe Flash Player, I can help. ;)

Comment: @wizlog Well, i know it too :P Its at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Load a VM and limit its CPU?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of throttling the CPU, you can slow down Flash games using [Cheat Engine](http://cheatengine.org/)'s **Speedhack** feature. In summary, **Speedhack** works by modifying the timing routines that are called by a game to get the current time <sup>**1**</sup>.

1. Open up your favorite Flash game in your browser.
2. Launch Cheat Engine.
3. Click on the **Select Process** button at the top-left, find the process running the Flash Player plugin <sup>*(see note below)*</sup>, and then click **Open**.

   [image: process]
4. Check the **Enable Speedhack** option on the right.

   [image: speedcheck]

   If you get an **error**, you've selected the wrong process!

   [image: error]
5. Change the **Speed** from `1.0` to a different value and then click **Apply**. In this case, you want the game to be slower, so make it less than `1.0`. For example, `0.5` would run the game slower, at `50 %` normal speed.

   [image: speed]
6. Return to your game. It should be playing at the new speed!

> **Note**: I use trial and error to find the correct process. However, if you just opened the game, it is usually the most recent Flash Player or browser process at the bottom of the list.

---

**References:**

<sup>**1**</sup> [Cheat Engine Internals: Speedhack](http://wiki.cheatengine.org/index.php?title=Cheat_Engine:Internals#Speedhack)

Comment: @iglvzx I tried that, received no error message, and the game speed remained unchanged.  Do you know why this could be?

Comment: I tried slowing down my browsers process and that worked.  Thanks!

Comment: @wizlog Yeah. It's mostly guessing, when finding the process.

Answer (score 1):

You can try lower the voltage for your processor in the BIOS settings. This will limit the resources a bit. You can create a simple c++ program that is filling all the memmory and using 100 % of cpu time.

this is for CPU usage:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main() {
    double start, end;
    double runTime;
    start = omp_get_wtime();
    int num = 1,primes = 0;

    int limit = 1000000;

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) reduction(+ : primes)
    for (num = 1; num <= limit; num++) { 
        int i = 2; 
        while(i <= num) { 
            if(num % i == 0)
                break;
            i++; 
        }
        if(i == num)
            primes++;
//      printf("%d prime numbers calculated\n",primes);
    }

    end = omp_get_wtime();
    runTime = end - start;
    printf("This machine calculated all %d prime numbers under %d in %g seconds\n",primes,limit,runTime);

    return 0;
}
```

About the memory - setup the Oracle Virtual Host. Install some system as the virtual machine and give it lots of memory to use. Of fire couple of virtual machines. this is the easiest non programming way i can think of.

For flash games slowdown in particular you can use : http://www.cheatengine.org/downloads.php

I found the video with the guide how to use cheatengine: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2W6L1iqGUR0

Comment: Lower the voltage? How far? What would that C++ program look like? Please extend your answer to include all necessary details :)

Comment: C++ program updated in answer. how to go with voltage? depands on your courage:) but its best to do little steps.

Comment: Lowering the voltage will not make that much of a difference. Additionally, this will be system wide.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to search out a CPU throttling program.  Several exist, though the only one that I have tried is [winThrottle](http://www.oldskool.org/pc/throttle) (and that was some time ago).  It makes its changes system-wide, not per program, but they are easy enough to turn on and off when you want (no rebooting required).