# Slow down clock/timer of a Linux program

Tags: linux, time, user-interface, clock, timer

Sometimes a Linux program requiring fast user interaction/manual dexterity runs too fast for me to keep up. Examples include video games and video players that don't let you control the speed.

How can I slow down the clock for that one process, so that I can interact with the program at a slower rate?

<sub>This question is the same as [How can I slow down the framerate of a Flash game?](https://superuser.com/questions/454534/how-can-i-slow-down-the-framerate-of-a-flash-game), except that that question's answer is a Windows-only program to do this. I'm [therefore asking a related question for Linux](http://meta.superuser.com/a/3751/34598).</sub>